# Item in local storage is undefined

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Here the login method will return the token so I'm setting the token to local storage in login method and in auth.header function I'm justing getting the token and I'm using that token in getAllTweet. This getAllTweets methods accept token as parameter.
In login method console.log(responce.data) here it's printing the token but in getAllTweets it displaying error as undefined.

```
login(loginId, password) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + "login", {
        loginId,
        password
        
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.data) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data));
        }
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
});


export default function authHeader() {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

  // if (user && user.token) {
    // console.log(user);
    // console.log(user.token);
    return token;
    // return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.accessToken }; // for Spring Boot back-end
    //return { 'x-access-token': user.accessToken };       // for Node.js Express back-end
  // } else {
  //   return {};
  // }
}
getAllTweet(authHeader) {
return axios.get(API_URL + 'all',{
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authHeader} ` },
});
```

}

Comment: you need to await for login function then you can call the getAllTweet

Comment: How do you call getAlltweet function..  it seems like you are not passing the token as params while calling the getAlltweet function..    I think you are confusing with the  authHeader function & the authHeader params in the getAlltweet function..

Comment: @Dibakar Halder i am calling the getallTweet after login only

Comment: @sms in that case how to pass token as parameter and how to get authHeader return value as header in getAllTweets

Answer (score 1):

do it like this. it will work as expected.

```
function authHeader() {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  return token;
}
getAllTweet() {
return axios.get(API_URL + 'all',{
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authHeader()} ` },
});
```

Comment: if i wrote like that then i am getting error like authHeader is not a function

Comment: do not pass as a parameter. 

`getAllTweet() {
return axios.get(API_URL + 'all',{
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authHeader()} ` },
});`

Comment: it works as expected for me..

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getAuthHeader() {
    const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')).then(token => {
      return { Authorization: `Bearer ${token} `}
  });
}

// using
const header = await getAuthHeader()
```

Comment: if i want to return only token can i write return token;

Comment: yes, can you write a return token.